# Find repayment amount on loan repaying a partial amount of the principal in a definite period of time.

Tags: finance

I'm trying to calculate the **Monthly payment amount** on a loan where I want to be able to define the **Principal amount** that should be repaid and an **Outstanding balance** after the repayments.

Example:

**1749€** is the initial principal amount supposed to be paid in **24 months** but I want to take **486,44€** of it and repay that amount in **6 months** with a **10% APR compounded monthly**. So at the end of the 6 months period, I should have an outstanding balance of **1262,66€**.

the amount should be **93,96€** but can't find the perfect formula for it.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the **1749€** not accrue interest as well?

Comment: Yep! that's exactly the point!

Comment: Your question seems in conflict then, if you pay 486,44€ you'll have more than 1262,66€ left at the end of the six months. So which do you want? To pay 486,44€ or to have 1262,66€ ? Do you want to make these payments in equal proportion every month for six months?

Comment: When I say 486,44 it's the principal part that is paid in 6 months. 563,85€ will be the total I'll pay which include the interests during that period (93,98*6). So I should then have a balance of 1262,44€ at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm interpreting your question correctly. Let me know.

You have a loan for 1749 with **annual interest** (APR) at 10% compounded monthly. You want to make monthly payments for six months so that the outstanding balance will be 1262,66 at the end.

The formula is this

$$P = \dfrac{r}{(1+r)^n -1}(PV(1+r)^n - OB)$$

where

- $r$ is in the interest rate
- $n$ is the number of periods (months)
- $PV$ is the initial loan amount
- $OB$ is the outstanding balance you desire

So with $r=0,10/12$, $n=6$, $PV=1749$, and $OB=1262,66$ we can solve for $P$ and find
$P=93,96$. So in order to have an outstanding balance of $1262,66$ at the end of the six months, you need to pay $93,96$ a month or a total amount of $93,96*6=563,76$.

**Addendum:** I hope I can provide you with some intuition so this isn't just a formula. Hopefully you know

$$PV(1+r)^n$$

gives the total amount due with interest. So

$$PV(1+r)^n - OB$$

is the total amount you'll have to pay in order for $OB$ to be left. Say you pay $P$ each period. You take out the loan on January 1. You make your first payment on February 1. When the 5 months have gone by, that first payment will have $P(1+r)^5$ value. On March 1 you make your second payment $P$. When 4 of the remaining months have gone by that second payment will have $P(1+r)^4$ value. Continue this for April 1, May 1, and so on. Let's call $TP$ the total payment. Hopefully it is clear that

$$TP = P + P(1+r)^1 + P(1+r)^2 + P(1+r)^3 + P(1+r)^4 + P(1+r)^5$$

This can seem very magical, but bear with me. We can simplify this with a clever trick. Multiply by (1+r) and subtract to get

\begin{align*}
    TP(1+r) &= P(1+r) + P(1+r)^2 + P(1+r)^3 + P(1+r)^4 + P(1+r)^5 + P(1+r)^6\\\\   
    -\phantom{y=}&\\    
    TP &= P + P(1+r)^1 + P(1+r)^2 + P(1+r)^3 + P(1+r)^4 + P(1+r)^5\\
   \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_&\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ \\
    TP(1+r) - TP &= P(1+r)^6 - P    
\end{align*}

Now we can solve for $TP$
\begin{align}
TP((1+r) - 1) &= P((1+r)^6 - 1 )\\
TP &= P\dfrac{(1+r)^6 - 1 }{(1+r) - 1)}\\
&=P\dfrac{(1+r)^6 - 1}{r}
\end{align}

Now we can find the payment amount by setting total payment equal to total balance minus left over balance.
\begin{align}
TP &= PV(1+r)^6 - OB\\
P\dfrac{(1+r)^6 - 1}{r} &= PV(1+r)^6 - OB\\
P &= \dfrac{r}{(1+r)^6 - 1}(PV(1+r)^6 - OB)
\end{align}

This was for $n=6$ but you can extrapolate to general $n$. I hope this provides some insight.

Comment: Thanks, @Almacomet for your help, I think you understood well my question, and my mistake is on the way I expressed the interest rate, I see that you apply 10%/ month where It should be 0.833% (10%/12). I will test it with the right interest rate...

Comment: I tested with the right interest rate and indeed the formula is correct! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @ALM83 I changed to fit what you have described. As a general note, the phrasing is "10% annual rate compounded monthly" or "10% APR compounded monthly." I also added a derivation.

Comment: Great! Yeah, I've seen, I'll adapt my description as well. I see that you might have forgotten a figure from the first answer with the 10% "P=237,93". Thank you for the derivation indeed it will help to understand the formula.